# jQuery UI Tooltip, on an image map how can I get the ID of the <area> into the tooltip content

Tags: image, jquery-ui, imagemap, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have an image wth mapped areas. Each of the areas has an ID, Coords, etc.. I would like to show the [jQuery ui tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) and include the id of the `<area>` in the tooltip. Here is code in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css' />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip(
        {
            content: 'My ID is: ' + this.id,
            track: true
        });
});
```

Here is some example html:

```
<img src="map.jpg" usemap="#coord" alt="a map" />
<map id="coord">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,10" id="Z1" title="zone 1 of 100" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="11,0,20,10" id="Z2" title="zone 2 of 100" />
</map>
```

What I hope to have the tooltip show in this case is, 'My ID is: Z1' and 'My ID is Z2'.

Unfortunately the tooltip shows '**My ID is: undefined**' in both cases.

If I change the `this.id` to just `id`, the javascript breaks with message '**ReferenceError: id is not defined**'.

And using `$(this)` gives '**My ID is: [object Object]**'. Which leads me to try `JSON.stringify($(this))` and I get a tooltip looking something like:

> My ID is: {"0":{"location":
>
> {},"jQuery111107594155618357165":1},"context":
>
> {"location":
>
> {},"jQuery111107594155618357165":1},"length":1}

Whoa! I am stumped trying to get that ID.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I am trying to get the id into that tooltip function so that I can use ajax to call up some data. I know I could create a hidden div with the info waiting for the onmouseover of the map area, but I would prefer not to load all that data (over a 100 queries) when the typical use will go to a specific area and just need that data. I would make a click function to run it but the map areas are linked and redirect on click.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery UI, just use the default fuctionality. 
Tooltips can be attached to any element, so put the id in html.

```
<map id="coord">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,10" id="Z1" title="z1" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="11,0,20,10" id="Z2" title="z2" />
</map>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }
    });
  });
 </script>

  <style>
  .ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .ui-tooltip {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #333;
  }
  .arrow {
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -16px;
  }
  .arrow.top {
    top: -16px;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .arrow.left {
    left: 20%;
  }
  .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px -5px black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .arrow.top:after {
    bottom: -20px;
    top: auto;
  }
```

Also, with Bootstrap, I think you can use popover, something like this:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var element = popup.getElement();
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  var id=evt.id;
  $(element).popover('destroy');
  popup.setPosition(coordinate);
  $(element).popover({
    'placement': 'top',
    'animation': false,
    'html': true,
    'content': '<p>The location you clicked was:</p><code>' + coordinate + '</code>'
  });
  $(element).popover('show');
});
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Madalina, thanks for your suggestions. I am trying to get the ID in the content because I need it to perform an ajax operation using that ID. I'll edit my question to reflect that desire as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Chris, I understand your reason, but you already have the id in the html and I think you can do there the ajax operation.

Comment: Anyway, in the second example, you can put the id in this line: 'content': '<p>The location you clicked was:</p><code>' + id+ '</code>'. I hope my suggestions help you.